# Cordova in VS 2017 emptying android platform folder when debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, firebase

I have an App built in Cordova in Visual Studio 2017.

I tried addding a pluggin for firebase (cordova-plugin-firebase) through the config.xml page, and on my next run it told me it could not find index.html.

I tried figuring out what went wrong, and I noticed that everytime I run the code, it actually empties nearly everything in the platforms/android folder. The only thing left is google-services.json and in the src the firebase plugin code. Even though I actually uninstalled the firebase plugin, it's the only thing that stays there.

I re-copied the platform from a backup, but it fails every time I try to build and then the platform folder is empty again.

Is there any file that I need to check or modify to fix this?

Comment: you are editing the wrong one directory (even if this may appear convenient for testing).

Comment: what apache cordova version and cordova-android versions are you using?